# Widget in Adobe AIR that starts in the systray

Tags: adobe, air

thanks in advance.

I need to develop a simple widget.

A traffic light green and red icon to check some services.

I made all the graphic and the icon 16*16 to make an icon in the systray of winXp.
That's ok.

But:
I need that **the application starts in the systray without the main area** and therefore clicking the icon the main area appears.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is make your main application window invisible by default. And set a DockIcon at the start of your application.
You can set the initialWindows property to false in the [application descriptor file](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=File_formats_1.html). The SystemTray can be set by using [flash.desktop.SystemTrayIcon](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/SystemTrayIcon.html).

If you're working with HTML what you'll need to to is pretty much the same. Your descriptor file should not show the initial window and the SystemTray icon can be set by using `air.NativeApplication.nativeApplication.icon.bitmaps`. After a quick Google search I found this on the [Adobe site](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/html/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118676a4af7-8000.html):

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script src="AIRAliases.js" language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 
    var iconLoadComplete = function(event) 
    { 
        air.NativeApplication.nativeApplication.icon.bitmaps = [event.target.content.bitmapData]; 
    } 

    air.NativeApplication.nativeApplication.autoExit = false; 
    var iconLoad = new air.Loader(); 
    var iconMenu = new air.NativeMenu(); 
    var exitCommand = iconMenu.addItem(new air.NativeMenuItem("Exit")); 
    exitCommand.addEventListener(air.Event.SELECT,function(event){ 
            air.NativeApplication.nativeApplication.icon.bitmaps = []; 
            air.NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit(); 
    }); 

    if (air.NativeApplication.supportsSystemTrayIcon) { 
        air.NativeApplication.nativeApplication.autoExit = false; 
        iconLoad.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(air.Event.COMPLETE,iconLoadComplete); 
        iconLoad.load(new air.URLRequest("icons/AIRApp_16.png")); 
        air.NativeApplication.nativeApplication.icon.tooltip = "AIR application"; 
        air.NativeApplication.nativeApplication.icon.menu = iconMenu; 
    } 

    if (air.NativeApplication.supportsDockIcon) { 
        iconLoad.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(air.Event.COMPLETE,iconLoadComplete); 
        iconLoad.load(new air.URLRequest("icons/AIRApp_128.png")); 
        air.NativeApplication.nativeApplication.icon.menu = iconMenu; 
    } 

</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: One question... I have to make all of this without Flash. It's possible to do that only in the .xml without actionscript?

Comment: But I have another problem now. 
I know that's so much...
If i start the app with <visible>true</visible> the app is visible, with <visible>false</visible> is not visible.
I would like that the window appears when I click on the icon.

And the position should be above the icon like a toast message with my graphics...

I search on google if you are tired to help a AIR dummy like me :)

Comment: I found it for the positioning, the onclick event on the icon is not necessary.

Comment: so did you found all your answers? (I'm not really sure by your last comment)

Comment: No, there is another question :)

To make it easy: I'm a graphic designer, I know very well html+css but not actionscript and my boss don't want to pay flash and I need to make a moke-up static in which I need to show some services, all in xml+html+css.


I found all that I need but the app now start with a fixed position (x, y), so it's good for a screenshot and for a screen with the same dimension than mine.


I searched (and I'm still searching) something to position the window application "botton-right" over the systray icon.

Comment: I think it's better if you made a new question for that, so you can close this one by accepting the answer.